# Get image dimensions before downloading

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to check the image dimensions (i.e. height and width) before downloading (or partially downloading) the image from a URL? I have found ways to get the image size, but that doesn't help.

Basically I want to calculate the correct height of a UITableView row before the image is downloaded. Is this possible?

Comment: Depends entirely on your backing web service. Unless you can either specify the dimensions or get metadata before requesting the image data itself, downloading's the only way to know.

Comment: Well, this has nothing to do with iOS or Swift... but you can make the `UIImageView` you're putting the image in whatever size you want...

Comment: Yes I will be resizing the image, but that doesn't help calculate the height of the UITableView row because some images may be portrait and others landscape - if portrait it will require larger row height than landscape. This can be calculated after download but scrolling ahead before images are downloaded will be a problem because it wont know what height to draw the row.

Comment: if you can have access to the image's header (anyhow) or the API provides such information for you directly – then yes.

Comment: You could do it with server-side scripting (if the computer that runs the script hosts the images and if the script has access to the images).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a partial download of the image data and then extract the image size from that. You will have to get the data structure of the image format you are using and parse it to some extent. It is possible and not that hard if you are capable of lower level coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by accessing its header details
In **Swift 3.0** below code will help you,

```
 if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url! as CFURL, nil) {
     if let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as Dictionary? {
          let pixelWidth = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth] as! Int
          let pixelHeight = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight] as! Int
          print("the image width is: \(pixelWidth)")
          print("the image height is: \(pixelHeight)")
       }
   }
```

Comment: This will probably download the whole image first.

Answer (score -1):

Create a IBOutlet of HeightConstraint
e.g Here image is in 16:9 ratio from server
This will automatically adjust height for all screen. ImageView ContentMode is AspectFit

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
cnstHeight.constant = (self.view.frame.width/16)*9
}
```

Answer (score -4):

**Swift 4** Method:

```
func getImageDimensions(from url: URL) -> (width: Int, height: Int) {
        if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, nil) {
            if let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as Dictionary? {
                let pixelWidth = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth] as! Int
                let pixelHeight = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight] as! Int
                return (pixelWidth, pixelHeight)
            }
        }
        return (0, 0)
    }
```

Comment: Do you understand that this will actually download the image?

Comment: @Sulthan YES. I AM AWARE. If you have a better solution, post here, rather than downvoting

Comment: Then it does not actually answer the question. The real answer is that there is no method possible unless the API can provide image dimensions separately.

Comment: I checked in UICollectionView and working fine. This can be the temporary solution. You know the real answer then write it in answer, don't write to me in the comment. Did you get me?

Comment: This is not even a temporary solution. Also, it blocks the main thread to download the images. If you have multiple images in the collection view, it will send a request for all of them, it downloads them, checks the size and then throws them away. That has nothing to do with the solution the OP wanted.